# Suppress/Remove Appendices cover page

Tags: appendices

I grabbed this sample code from internet and it gives me an Appendix with a cover page. How can I change the code to remove this? Obs, I use `\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}`

```
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit} \label{app:foobar}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{foo}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \textbf{ a } & \textbf{ b }\\
    1 & 3 \\
    2 & 4\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
  \chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  The behaviour will depend on other features of your document include which class you are using.  Please complete your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating your set-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `page` option to the appendix package. See [the manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) for more details.

Comment: For future readers, this probably refers to using the command `\appendixpageoff` declaration before the beginning of the `appendices` environment.